# Top 3 items to be shown in wide format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
code    attribute   rank_count
394 Feminine    9
394 Fresh   9
394 Heavy   8
418 Soft    13
418 Fresh   12
418 Clean   11
539 Fresh   14
539 Soft    14
539 Feminine    11
555 Feminine    9
555 Heavy   8
555 Soft    7
```

The above dataframe has attributes field with various attributes for the code field, they are ranked in the third column, now I need it in the below format of top 1 top2 top 3, which should look like

```
code    top1    top2    top3
394 Feminine (9)    Fresh (9)   Heavy (8)
418 Soft(13)    Fresh (12)  Clean (11)
539 Fresh(14)   soft(14)    Feminine(11)
```

The attributes I am unable to use pivot table as the attributes are many, I am trying to rearrange the data in a top3 fashion

Comment: There are always 3 rows per groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(list)

for code, attr, rank in df.itertuples(index=False):
    d[code].append((attr, rank))

d = {k: sorted(v, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3] for k, v in d.items()}

res = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()

print(res)

   index              0            1               2
0    394  (Feminine, 9)   (Fresh, 9)      (Heavy, 8)
1    418     (Soft, 13)  (Fresh, 12)     (Clean, 11)
2    539    (Fresh, 14)   (Soft, 14)  (Feminine, 11)
3    555  (Feminine, 9)   (Heavy, 8)       (Soft, 7)
```

You can change column names and provide additional formatting as necessary. In my opinion, it is a *better* idea to store tuples than converting numeric data to strings.

**If you really need a string representation...**

You can use `pd.Series.apply`:

```
for col in [0, 1, 2]:
    res[col] = res[col].apply(lambda x: '{0} ({1})'.format(x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: I need the braces only on the numbers  eg heavy (8)

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham, I'm confused. *There are no braces in my answer.*

Comment: I need the braces only on the numbers eg heavy (8)

Comment: There are no braces in my answer.. This is a representation of tuples..

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = (df.sort_values(['code','rank_count'], ascending=(True, False))
       .assign(attribute=df['attribute'] + ' (' + df['rank_count'].astype(str) + ')', 
               g=df.groupby('code').cumcount() + 1)
       .query('g < 4')
       .set_index(['code','g'])['attribute']
       .unstack()
       .add_prefix('top')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   code          top1        top2           top3
0   394  Feminine (9)   Fresh (9)      Heavy (8)
1   418     Soft (13)  Fresh (12)     Clean (11)
2   539    Fresh (14)   Soft (14)  Feminine (11)
3   555  Feminine (9)   Heavy (8)       Soft (7)
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) per 2 columns
2. Join columns `attribute` with `rank_count`, add new count column by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
3. If necessary filter top `3` by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
4. Reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
5. [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for cleaner final `DataFrame`

EDIT:

Solution without `assign`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['code','rank_count'], ascending=(True, False))
df['attribute']=df['attribute'] + ' (' + df['rank_count'].astype(str) + ')'
df['g'] = df.groupby('code').cumcount() + 1

df = (df.query('g < 4')
       .set_index(['code','g'])['attribute']
       .unstack()
       .add_prefix('top')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   code          top1        top2           top3
0   394  Feminine (9)   Fresh (9)      Heavy (8)
1   418     Soft (13)  Fresh (12)     Clean (11)
2   539    Fresh (14)   Soft (14)  Feminine (11)
3   555  Feminine (9)   Heavy (8)       Soft (7)
```

Comment: I am not getting the braces ( ) for some reason in my output 
.assign(attribute=df['attribute'] + ' (' + df['rank_count'].astype(str) + ')',

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - problem is it working only in last version of pandas, `0.23.0`, for bellow try `.assign(attribute=lambda x: x['attribute'] + ' (' + x['rank_count'].astype(str) + ')', 
               g=lambda x: x.groupby('code').cumcount() + 1)`

Comment: Iam using pandas pandas==0.21.1

Comment: No .assign(attribute=lambda x: x['attribute'] + ' (' + x['rank_count'].astype(str) + ')', g=lambda x: x.groupby('code').cumcount() + 1)  Not working still without braces only

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - Please cehck solution without `.assign`

Comment: could please share the command with out assign..Iam getting syntax errors

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - Maybe some `)` is missing, edited solution is without `.assign`

Comment: yes the edited solution works with ( )  , Thanks a ton

Comment: Super :) Can you accept solution? Click to empty tick under `1` in left upper corner of my answer. Thanks.